# Gallery Thumbnail (left/right) Scroll Performance Android Chrome Sluggish and Unresponsive

Tags: magento2, mobile, gallery

#### Preconditions (*)

1. Magento 2.2.7 and Magento 2.3 Product Gallery
2. Product page gallery with sample data is installed on the luma theme with additional images (minimum 5+).

#### Steps to reproduce (*)

1. Configure product gallery to use thumbnails on mobile.

```
<var name="breakpoints">
    <var name="mobile">
        <var name="conditions">
            <var name="max-width">767px</var>
        </var>
        <var name="options">
            <var name="options">
                  <var name="arrows">true</var>
                  <var name="navarrows">true</var>
                  <var name="nav">thumbs</var>
             </var>
       </var>
   </var>
</var>
```

1. Navigate to a product page with more than 5 images on Chrome Android or Chrome Dev in mobile mode.
2. Attempt to scroll through the *thumbnail* gallery and you will note sluggish/slow performance.

#### Expected result (*)

1. Smooth responsive behaviour

#### Actual result (*)

1. Sluggish and unresponsive

#### Additional information

1. Video of poor performance: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjjnxsiohgsn8mf/20190206_095707.mp4?dl=0